# proof that extensibility of every character $\chi_0$ on a subgroup H to a character on G, when H is a subroup of an abelian group G

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have trouble understanding a proposition and its proof.

proposition: Let G be a finite abelian group and H ⊂ G a subgroup. Every character $χ_0$ on H can be extended to a character on G.

Proof: We proceed by induction on the order of the quotient group |G/H|. If |G/H| =
1, then G = H, the character χ0 is already a character of G.
If the order of the quotient |G/H| > 1, choose a class gH of G/H such that gH $\neq$ H and denote by
M/H = <gH> the cyclic group of G/H generated by <gH>.
If M $\neq$ G, both |M/H| and G/M are both of order less than G/H and hence we can extend $\chi_0$, first to a character of M and then to a character of the whole G.
We may assume then that M = G and G/H = M/H = <gH> is cyclic. Let n = |G/H|. We have then that
$g^nH$ = H and hence $g^n\in H$. Choose a complex number ξ such that $χ_0(g^n) = ξ^n$ and define the map: $χ(g^rh) = ξ^rχ_0(h)$
for all n > r ≥ 0 and h ∈ H. The map is well defined because the cosets
$H_r = \{g^rh | 0 ≤ r < n, h ∈ H\}$
form a partition of G. We can prove that the map defined this way is a character on
the whole G and it extendes $χ_0$.

Quesitons:

1. What does it exactly mean by that a character $X_0$ can be extended on G? Does it mean that the extended $\chi_0$ will give out the same values in C(Complex plane) for the elements in H and also give values in C for the elements in G?
2. When M $\neq$ G, why/how can we extend $\chi_0$ to a character of M and to G? I don't clearly understand what is going on here.
3. for the map $\chi(g^rh)=\xi^r\chi_0(h)$, with $\chi(g^rh)$, when the number of elements of G is m, we have $\chi(g^rh)^m=\chi(g^{rm}h^m)=1$. will $\chi(g^{rm})$ be 1 because number of elements of $<g>$ should divide m by lagrange's throerm and $\chi(h^m)$ also that number of elements of H has to divide m?

Comment: (1) yes. (2) it's a proof by induction. The induction hypothesis is that we can extend from a subgroup to a group when the order of the quotient group is smaller than the order of $G/H$, and this hypothesis holds for both $M/H$ and $G/M$, so by hypothesis we can extend from $H$ to $M$ and then from $M$ to $G$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In this proof, does it show why the hypothesis holds?
Is it the part when we assume that M=G? Because we can assume that G is M and show that our character on H can be extended to M, and from M, we can find another K/M=<gM> and keep going on?

Comment: $M/H$ and $G/M$ are both of order smaller than that of $G/H$, unless $M=G$, so either the induction hypothesis holds (and we're done) or $M=G$ and we make a different argument.

Comment: Is that OK, momo?